# Where I can print receipts/invoices from Hiscox insurance company?

Tags: hiscox

[Hiscox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiscox) is a global business liability specialist insurer and it's quite big.
But the problem is, I couldn't find any way of printing my receipts/invoices for their insurance policy to claim the financial costs. And on their [website](http://www.hiscox.co.uk/) it seems that I can't even log-in anywhere. I've sent them few e-mails last year, but it seems they're not responding to their mailbox at all.

Anybody having the same problem?

Comment: I've tried businessinsurance@hiscox.co.uk, but without success. I didn't receive any password, but I'll double check. I've called them, but they've send me only the Schedule of payments, not receipts or invoices. I'll try the link which you've posted and see what I can find there, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following things:

- Try to log-in to [Hiscox members area](https://www.hiscoxtravelinsurance.co.uk/services/account/) (as suggested by pnuts). Your password can be found in the email that was sent to you when you completed the quotation process. If you didn't receive your login details, or are unable to find them, you can [request a new password](https://www.hiscoxtravelinsurance.co.uk/services/account/forgotten.asp). Alternatively you can contact the call centre on 0845 643 6046 and they'll resend your details to you.
- Call support centre and ask for the invoices, they'll send it to your e-mail.
- If you're using Direct Debit payment, check your e-mail for attached Direct Debit Payment confirmation document, it should be fine.
- Check your bank statement, search for Hiscox and print the transactions containing your search.

Comment: That's for Hiscox Travel Insurance, different site than what the OP linked to.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the invoices on screen, just use the PrntScrn function key:  it takes a copy of the screen at the time, which you can paste into another program and then print from.